# How to generate JHipster application into a specific directory?

Tags: node.js, jhipster

Suppose I modified the source code of generator-jhipster repo and I would like to generate my "custom" JHipster application into a specific directory, how would I accomplish this task?

After installing JHipster:

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

I would be able to generate the application with:

```
jhipster
```

However, this command runs the application directly from the JHipster repository.

Since I modified the source code, I could generate the application locally by running:

```
node jhipster.js
```

in the ../cli directory.

The problem is, running this command in cli directory will generate the application in the same directory (cli) and this is not what I want.
I need to find a way to export the application into a specific directory.

Note: I strongly believe this has something to do with process.cwd(), because that generates the application in the local directory, but I'm not sure exactly 
which source file to modify as I don't want to break anything.

Comment: Please don't create duplicate questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate jhipster application into a different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960459/how-to-generate-jhipster-application-into-a-different-directory)